# Counting input pulses with a raspberry pi 3 and showing the results

Tags: raspberry-pi

this is my first time working with a raspberry pi and also with structure code( full ladder coding here) My main objective is to connect 4 inputs on my raspberry pi GPIO, I need to count each pulse and display each one of them with a log (date and time) on a web page or any other suggestions to view the data.

Comment: Are you interested in their duration, or just when they start? Do you know the sorts of durations and frequencies you expect pulses at?

Comment: I have a pulse signal from 2 diferent tests, each tests tells me a PASS or FAIL signal trough a electric pulse, I need to know at the end of a day how many tests failed or passed  EDIT: the electric pulse is like a sec on then off

Comment: How long between pulses roughly please?

Comment: depends mostly on the test, but at least 5min between each test

Comment: If you haven't done much coding, you might get on well with `Node-RED` and its graphical programming. Maybe add a dashboard with `Grafana` if you want something pretty. A different idea would be Python with `gpiozero` package and logging into a simple CSV file, and use Python's http.server to make website.